# Find out whether the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k!+1)!}{((k+1)!)!}$ is convergent or not.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k!+1)!}{((k+1)!)!}
$$
I have to discover whether this series is convergent or divergent. I already tried ratio test and Stirling's approximation. In both cases I struggled with difficult calculations that did not lead me to the answer. Perhaps there is another approach to this problem?

Comment: "I have to discover whether..." Then you should do it, and not ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $$(k+1)!-1>k!+1\forall k\geq 2$$
$$\Longrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k!+1)!}{((k+1)!)!}=1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(k!+1)!}{((k+1)!)!}$$
$$=1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(k!+1)!}{(k+1)!((k+1)!-1)!}$$
$$<1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)!}$$
which is finite. Hence, this series is convergent by comparison test.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This series is convergent because $((k+1)!)!$ is much bigger than $(k!+1)!$ so we can compare it :

Notice that if $a_n > b_n$, then $a_n! \ge b_n! \times a_n$, and so we get

$$\frac{b_n!}{a_n!} \le \frac{1}{a_n}$$

In your case, we have $(k+1)! = k \times k! + k!$, then for $k \ge 2$ we have $(k+1)! > k!+1$, and we deduce

$$\frac{(k!+1)!}{((k+1)!)!} \le \frac{1}{(k+1)!}$$

So your series is convergent by comparison.

Comment: I think I got something similar by putting in low values of k and noticing that $\frac{(k!+1)!}{((k+1)!)!} \approx \frac{m!}{((k+1)m)!}$ with $m = (k!)!$, and then realizing that, since m > 1, $\frac{m!}{((k+1)m)!} < \frac{1}{(k+1)!}$.

And the rest is filling in the gaps/ making it rigorous.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$(k+1)!=(k+1)k!=k!+1+(kk!-1)$$

therefore for $k$ large

$$((k+1)!)!\ge [k!+1+(kk!-1)][k!+1+(kk!-2)](k!+1)!\ge (k!+1)!k!$$

therefore the given series converges by comparison test.